# Is it natural to have some small buzzing in the guitar?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, intonation, buzz

I have an Ernie Ball Music Man Majesty which plays extremely well. When I bought it it was set-up.

After 6 months I have noticed that the low E-string buzzes slightly if I pluck it moderately strongly.

I know that for lead guitar the distance of the E-string from the fretboard must be at 1.5mm or 1.75mm. Mine is exactly at 1.75mm, therefore this seems to be ok.

I just don't know if it is natural for the first frets to have some minimal buzzing or if there should be none. On the other hand this seems weird if you want a very low action.

- What is the case?
- Is there some book/reference where these things are clearly
  explained?

Comment: My opinion is no, not on a really good instrument.  I have played on plenty of them that are perfect... unfortunately for me, all of mine buzz somewhere. :^P

Comment: I see. But for very low action, is this possible?

Comment: Yes.. on a perfect instrument it is very possible.  Also.. strings could be your problem.. I have guitars that buzz with Ernie Ball but not with Dean Markley.  Not saying Balls are bad.. just saying try other brands.  Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I still have factory strings which are indeed Ernie Ball. I will ask my technician too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: 1.75mm at what fret?
What fret is buzzing? (If you fret on the first fret and it does away then it's that fret ... lets say it's the 7th fret ... you neck may need a trust adjustment... look down the neck, is it flat?

"I know that for lead guitar the distance of the E-string from the fretboard must be at 1.5mm or 1.75mm." 

??? Why must it be any measurement ... let alone two specific ones.

Do some troubleshooting. Is it the fret, neck, or perhaps even the nut.

Comment: If the buzzing is not stopping the note from sustaining, and the buzzing noise isn't obvious in the sound picked up by the pickups, then hearing a little fret buzz when you play the guitar without amplification isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those measurements are not gospel. There are a lot of factors involved in setting up a guitar - one important one is personal choice! It's far better to use eyes and ears setting up than a ruler and a feeler gauge!

The neck relief and action may have settled a little, causing buzz. But you hold back information as to where it buzzes. Open? 3rd fret only? All frets up to 6th? The saddle on the 6th string may have dropped slightly, and all it needs is raising a few thous. Far more information might help bring answers.

Comment: Thanks. It is only the first couple of frets of the low E string when plucked strikingly. The highly I mentioned is on the 12th fret.

Answer (score 0):

Necks are wood, and wood changes over time.  Humidity can be a factor, temperature can be a factor, etc.  The only way you can have a neck that never changes is to have it made out of something besides wood, maybe aluminum or some kind of composite.